# ios - imageFromCurrentFramebuffer from gpuimage lib saves black frame

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I'm applying list of filters to detect shape during camera capturing process. Once shape is detected - want to save it to photos for review. Googled for `imageFromCurrentFramebuffer`, but is always saves black picture.

```
// camera init
var videoCamera = GPUImageVideoCamera(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080, cameraPosition: .Back)
videoCamera!.outputImageOrientation = .Portrait;
videoCamera?.startCameraCapture()

// filter init
var houghTransformFilter = GPUImageHoughTransformLineDetector()
houghTransformFilter!.lineDetectionThreshold = 0.3
houghTransformFilter!.useNextFrameForImageCapture() //without this crashes
houghTransformFilter!.linesDetectedBlock = {
    // my custom shape detection logic
    if (found) {
        self.videoCamera?.pauseCameraCapture()
        var capturedImage:UIImage? = self.houghTransformFilter!.imageFromCurrentFramebuffer()
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedImage, nil, nil, nil); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.  You probably need to add this line before the call to grab the frame:

```
self.houghTransformFilter?.useNextFrameForImageCapture()
```